# .NET Core 6.0 JWT returns 400

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm using postman to test a new C# Web API but every single request that I do returns 400 even passing the bearer token that I get on login request (which works fine). Below I show my code.

CardController.cs

```
using CoreBusiness;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("/")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CardController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IJwtAuthenticationManager jwtAuthenticationManager;

        public CardController(IJwtAuthenticationManager jwtAuthenticationManager)
        {
            this.jwtAuthenticationManager = jwtAuthenticationManager;
        }

        // GET: api/<CardController>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("cards")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<CardController>/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<CardController>
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<CardController>/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<CardController>/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] UserLoginDto userLoginDto)
        {
            var token = jwtAuthenticationManager.Login(userLoginDto.Login, userLoginDto.Senha);

            if (token == null)
                return Unauthorized();
            else
                return Ok(token);
        }
    }
}
```

My JwtAuthenticationManager.cs

```
using CoreBusiness;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;

namespace WebApi
{
    public class JwtAuthenticationManager : IJwtAuthenticationManager
    {
        private readonly List<UserLoginDto> users = new List<UserLoginDto>
        {
            new UserLoginDto() { Login = "login", Senha = "pass" }
        };

        private readonly string key;

        public JwtAuthenticationManager(string key)
        {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public string Login(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (!users.Any(f => f.Login == userName && f.Senha == password))
            {
                return null;
            }

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var tokenKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName)
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenKey),
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
    }
}
```

My Pogram.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using WebApi;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var key = "my secret test key with minimum characters";
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IJwtAuthenticationManager>(new JwtAuthenticationManager(key));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key)),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Could you please help me. I already tried to change line position of authorization and authentication.

Actually I'm out of ideas.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Get rid of the newline character at the end of your URL in Postman, and you'll be golden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API controller doesnt support REST, only an attribute routing. So I recommend you

```
  [Route("[controller]/[action]/")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CardController : ControllerBase
  
       [HttpGet("~/cards")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<CardController>/5
        [HttpGet("~/cards/get/{id}")] // or "~/api/cards/get/{id}"
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
       ... and so on
```